# Moment.js change the midnight time reset

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Here is my current moment.js setup, and it works great! However, the `maxDate` changes over at midnight (it moves up one day). I am sure that is how it is supposed to work and it makes sense, but I need it to change over at say, 8 AM. I have done some searching to no avail, and maybe I am using incorrect terminology, but I'm not too familiar with this. Any help is appreciated.

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    maxSpan:{days:30},
    minDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    maxDate: moment().add(341, 'days'),
    startDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().add(2, 'days'),
    autoApply: true,
    opens: 'center'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    document.getElementById('start').value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    document.getElementById('end').value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  });
```

Edit: @Tim made a suggestion about using utcOffset. I couldn't get it to work and found this https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/747 . But I can't seem to get that suggestion to work.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try using UTC offset on the endDate: `endDate: moment().add(2, 'days').utcOffset("-08:00"),`

Comment: @Tim I changed my endDate line with yours and tested it. It didn't seem to make a difference. Edit: I also noticed I placed the wrong variable in there. Should be ```maxDate``` Trying it now.

Comment: @Tim Yeah, it doesn't seem to subtract the maxDate by one date. I extended it to 16 hours, and still nothing. I am reading up on ```utcOffset``` in hopes that this will work. I appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: Please note, with daterangepicker, you will need to have `timePicker: true` in order to work with times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @Tim for the suggestions. I really do appreciate the feedback. However, adding the times within my daterangepicker wasn't really an option. So, I handled it with an if statement and created a variable.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var today = new Date().getHours();
  if (today >= 0 && today < 8) {
    var maxDay = moment().add(340, 'days');
  }
  else {
    var maxDay = moment().add(341, 'days');
  }

  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    autoApply: true,
    maxSpan:{days:30},
    minDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    maxDate: maxDay,
    startDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    endDate: moment().add(1, 'days'),
    opens: 'center'
  }, function(start, end, label) {
    document.getElementById('start').value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    document.getElementById('end').value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  });});
```